# Convert two arrays into string separated by a special delimiter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame that looks like following:

```
+--+-----------------------+---------------------+
|id|                   type|                 name|
+--+-----------------------+---------------------+
| 1|[stars]                |[sun, altair, sirius]|
| 2|[solar system, planets]|[mars, earth]        |
| 3|[natural satellites]   |[moon, io, titan]    |
+--+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to add an extra column by concatenating the array from the `type` column and the array from the `name` column, but separating them with a semicolon `(;)` delimiter.

**Expected output:**

```
+--+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+
|id|                   type|                 name|                             result|
+--+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1|[stars]                |[sun, altair, sirius]|stars; sun, altair, sirius         |
| 2|[solar system, planets]|[mars, venus]        |solar system, planets; mars, venus |
| 3|[natural satellites]   |[moon, io, titan]    |natural satellites; moon, io, titan|
+--+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

I tried to apply `concat_ws` function, but I got the result, which is different from what I expected.

So, is it possible to get the desired output using `PySpark`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `concat_ws` once to join array entries using comma, then once more to join two results with semicolon.

```sql
SELECT id, type, name,
       concat_ws('; ', concat_ws(', ', type), concat_ws(', ', name)) as result
  FROM ...
```